# Issues with nested require statements with RequireJS and caching

Tags: javascript, caching, requirejs

I tried searching but couldn't find an issue that matches my problem. I've started to use RequireJS to manage my scripts and one thing I noticed is when I do nested requires, it looks to me like the 2nd required module fails to respect browser caching, forcing me to use something like urlArgs to get the browser to see the updated script. The initial required module works fine and when modified, I see the updated etag and appropriate request headers such as If-None-Match. The second required script though does not and browser dev tools just show it being returned from cache with a 200 status code, until I force refresh or again, use urlArgs.

Sample code below

```
require(["app"], function (App) { // Browser sees updated app script just fine after modification
    App.initialize({
        id: ' . $id . ',
        someOtherImportantOption: "' . $someOtherImportantValueFromServer . '"
    });

    require(["otherScript"]); // Browser fails to see updated otherScript when modified
});
```

If I just require otherScript on its own then it caches just fine, but I might rely on App being populated with a bunch of things from the server.